# The best friend a mother could have or anything for that matter

Tags: american-english, british-english

What is the meaning of sentence below?

Oh, my sweet daughter, who is not only my daughter but my best friend, the best friend a mother could have, **or anything for that matter**.

Source of information: https://youtu.be/O8_xIj0Nzx4?t=1688

Comment: idea: or anything a mother can have, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You have misheard, the mother says:

> ... or **anyone** for that matter.

*[for that matter](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/for-that-matter)* is a common spoken expression to stress that something else is also true.

*or anyone* is linked to *a mother*: the best friend a mother (or anyone) could have.

Comment: I've edited to clarify that the OP had misheard the key word.

Answer (score -3):

> Oh, my friend, you are not only my friend, but my best friend, or anything for that matter.

It does not matter whether you are from Paris, Kyoto, Jalalabad, Cairo, Mexico City, or Cleveland.

You know what it means.  It means RUN.